# How do I loopback 2 input streams + line-in to line-out? (12.04)

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, microphone, streaming

I'm trying to put together a simple Karaoke system with 2 microphones. I've fiddled with [the config from this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257992/how-can-i-use-pulseaudio-virtual-audio-streams-to-play-music-over-skype) and am able to get 1 mic to loopback, along with youtube, to the the line-out.

But I cannot seem to get 2 mics to loopback simultaneously. It appears I have to choose which input stream is selected in the *sounds app* on the inputs tab. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you add to the question the results of `pactl list short`.

Comment: sure. but where is that. link?

Comment: Actually, it's a command. Open terminal Ctrl+Alt+t, then run `pactl list short`

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to loopback multiple sources to same sink.

1. Check sources list (For me, I have only one microphone source: id=2)

   ```
   $ pactl list short sources
   0   alsa_output.pci-0000_01_00.1.hdmi-stereo.monitor    module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
   1   alsa_output.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo.monitor  module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   IDLE
   2   alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo   module-alsa-card.c  s16le 2ch 44100Hz   SUSPENDED
   ```
2. Create a new virtual sink

   ```
   pactl load-module module-null-sink sink_name=Virtual1 sink_properties=device.description=Virtual1
   ```
3. Loopback sources to Virtual1 sink (one by one), by id:

   ```
   pactl load-module module-loopback sink=Virtual1 source=2
   ```

   or by name:

   ```
   pactl load-module module-loopback sink=Virtual1 source=alsa_input.pci-0000_00_1b.0.analog-stereo
   ```

See [Share an audio playback stream through a live audio (video) conversation like Skype](https://askubuntu.com/questions/421014/share-an-audio-playback-stream-through-a-live-audio-video-conversation-like-sk/421056#421056)