# Are my choices really limited to stream sound or hear sound?

Tags: pulseaudio, streaming, avconv

I followed the instructions at [How can I use PulseAudio virtual audio streams to play music over Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257992/how-can-i-use-pulseaudio-virtual-audio-streams-to-play-music-over-skype) in order to load-module sinks. I can stream to my twitch feed no problem. My problem is that I can't hear the game sound myself. Only my stream can. Is there a way that I can stream my sound, as well as hear it while I'm streaming?

Comment: Is a combined sink an option? See http://askubuntu.com/questions/57319/analog-and-digital-audio-output-at-the-same-time