# Output audio from browser to discord with mic mix in

Tags: sound, pulseaudio, alsa, microphone

Tried to do things like it was described here [How can I use PulseAudio virtual audio streams to play music over Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257992/how-can-i-use-pulseaudio-virtual-audio-streams-to-play-music-over-skype#)
But last command `pactl load-module module-loopback`
Does not seem to be working. It should create some kind of input device accessible from programs, but it does not seem to be working. It does not show up in settings also.

Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS x86_64 (kde)

5.4.0-58-generic

Answer (score 0):

This problem is most easily and flexibly solved using a combination of both Pulse and Jack. This link is to a blog post for routing mic and other sound to Jitsi Meet in a browser. Scroll down to the "linux" section. The steps were written with an Ubuntu system in mind: https://www.fossbox.org.uk/?p=240

Answer (score 0):

Well I found ugly solution: [How can I use PulseAudio virtual audio streams to play music over Skype?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/257992/how-can-i-use-pulseaudio-virtual-audio-streams-to-play-music-over-skype#) this + installed pavcontrol, and in there when discord is launched I change input from whatever to virtual2. Still suggesting a better one.